# React webpack failing to build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to create my first React app and I am getting an error related to my `package.json` file. Any ideas why this is happening? It looks like it specifically doesn't like the `--output` portion of my code, but I am following a tutorial that required this piece.

The error log is directly from the link produced in the command line:

```
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v14.15.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle scheduler@0.20.1~prebuild: scheduler@0.20.1
6 info lifecycle scheduler@0.20.1~build: scheduler@0.20.1
7 verbose lifecycle scheduler@0.20.1~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle scheduler@0.20.1~build: PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\New User\leadmanager\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Users\New User\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle scheduler@0.20.1~build: CWD: C:\Users\New User\leadmanager
10 silly lifecycle scheduler@0.20.1~build: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'webpack --mode development .\\leadmanager\\frontend\\src\\index.js --output .\\leadmanager\\frontend\\static\\frontend\\main.js'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle scheduler@0.20.1~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle scheduler@0.20.1~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: scheduler@0.20.1 build: `webpack --mode development .\leadmanager\frontend\src\index.js --output .\leadmanager\frontend\static\frontend\main.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid scheduler@0.20.1
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\New User\leadmanager
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.15.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.10
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error scheduler@0.20.1 build: `webpack --mode development .\leadmanager\frontend\src\index.js --output .\leadmanager\frontend\static\frontend\main.js`
22 error Exit status 2
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "_from": "scheduler@^0.20.1",
  "_id": "scheduler@0.20.1",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-LKTe+2xNJBNxu/QhHvDR14wUXHRQbVY5ZOYpOGWRzhydZUqrLb2JBvLPY7cAqFmqrWuDED0Mjk7013SZiOz6Bw==",
  "_location": "/scheduler",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "range",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "scheduler@^0.20.1",
    "name": "scheduler",
    "escapedName": "scheduler",
    "rawSpec": "^0.20.1",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "^0.20.1"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/react-dom"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/scheduler/-/scheduler-0.20.1.tgz",
  "_shasum": "da0b907e24026b01181ecbc75efdc7f27b5a000c",
  "_spec": "scheduler@^0.20.1",
  "_where": "C:\\Users\\New User\\node_modules\\react-dom",
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "loose-envify"
    ]
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/facebook/react/issues"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "deprecated": false,
  "description": "Cooperative scheduler for the browser environment.",
  "files": [
    "LICENSE",
    "README.md",
    "build-info.json",
    "index.js",
    "tracing.js",
    "tracing-profiling.js",
    "unstable_mock.js",
    "unstable_post_task.js",
    "cjs/",
    "umd/"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://reactjs.org/",
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development .\\leadmanager\\frontend\\src\\index.js --output .\\leadmanager\\frontend\\static\\frontend\\main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode development .\\leadmanager\\frontend\\src\\index.js --output .\\leadmanager\\frontend\\static\\frontend\\main.js"
  },
  "name": "scheduler",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/facebook/react.git",
    "directory": "packages/scheduler"
  },
  "version": "0.20.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^5.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit older version of webpack, so instead of `--output` you should use `--output-path`